# Mac OS X Docker baseline aspnet error: libdl not found

Tags: asp.net, macos, docker, asp.net-core

Using boot2docker and Microsoft's baseline aspnet image with a basic `yo aspnet` project:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta7

COPY project.json /app/
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]
COPY . /app


EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "kestrel"]
```

I can build successfully with `docker build -t mvcapp .`, but when I try to run `docker run -i -p 5004:5004 -t mvcapp` I get the following error:

> System.DllNotFoundException: libdl   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.PlatformApis/LinuxApis:dlopen
>   (string,int)   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.PlatformApis+LinuxApis.LoadLibrary
>   (System.String dllToLoad) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Networking.Libuv.Load (System.String
>   dllToLoad) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.KestrelEngine..ctor (ILibraryManager
>   libraryManager, IApplicationShutdown appShutdownService) [0x00000] in
>   :0 ...

I've tried a few different base aspnet images with little success. Is there a special step for Mac OS X to get this working?

EDIT: I should add that running the same entrypoint command `dnx -p project.json kestrel` does work, and I can access localhost:5000 successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue on Ubuntu 15.04. 
I also tried adding "ENV RUNTIME_PACKAGES libunwind8 gettext libssl-dev libcurl3-dev zlib1g" in Dockerfile, but it doesn't work.
According to [Running-ASP.NET-5-beta4-in-Docker-with-DNX-runtime](https://alexanderzeitler.com/articles/Running-ASP.NET-5-beta4-in-Docker-with-DNX-runtime/) , it seemed the previous versions before beta7 worked fine.

I found I used wrong docker image "microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta7". After I did the following steps, it worked fine.

1. Get the right docker image by:
   docker pull microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta7-coreclr
2. Modify dockerfile:
   use "FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta7-coreclr" instead of "FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta7" and add "ENV RUNTIME_PACKAGES libunwind8, gettext, libssl-dev, libcurl3-dev, zlib1g"

Comment: Follow https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/dev/GettingStartedDeb.md, "libdl not found" doesn't appear. I think some operations missing in beta7's dockerfile.